why division doesn't work with #define numbers?
#define BLUR 2
#define LEN (2 * BLUR + 1) * (2 * BLUR + 1)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << 50 / LEN; // result is 50
}

the expected result is 2 but it's 50. I try another numbers but get the wrong answer. with other operation like *, + and - the output is valid but not with division.

Try to expand the macros on a paper  with a pencil.

Since you're using C++, you should use const or constexpr variables instead.

@3CxEZiVlQ is right. Remember that LEN isn't 25; it's (2 * BLUR + 1) * (2 * BLUR + 1).

Your title says "#define numbers", which I would expect to mean something like #define 25. What you have is more of a "#define expression".

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Further to what the others have stated, consider what the order of operations is.

it's explained early in any good C++ book. Please read a good one

Why are you even using #define? The primary building block for code in C++ should be functions not macros. static constexpr int blur = 2;  static constexpr int calculate_len(int value) = (2*(blur+1)) * (2*(blur+1)); and then static constexpr len = calculate_len(blur);

if you write macros you must use the compilers feature to see the output after preprocessing, for gcc it is -E others have it too.

LEN expands to (2 * 2 + 1) * (2 * 2 + 1), so your expression expands to
50 / (2 * 2 + 1) * (2 * 2 + 1)

In C++, division and multiplication have the same precedence, and associate left to right - effectively giving the same order of operations as in ordinary paper-and-pencil arithmetic.  So the division gets evaluated before the outer multiplication.  You are computing
(50 / (2 * 2 + 1)) * (2 * 2 + 1)

which is indeed 50.
Just because some tokens came from expanding a macro, does not automatically make them grouped into a single expression.  When you want this, you have to include parentheses in the definition.  So change your macro definition to
#define LEN ((2 * BLUR + 1) * (2 * BLUR + 1))

However, in modern C++ it is better to use a constexpr variable, and in that case the issue doesn't arise.
constexpr int BLUR = 2;
constexpr int LEN = (2 * BLUR + 1) * (2 * BLUR + 1);

will work as expected.
